# Autoejecutable rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

Tengo un script en R

Creo un fichero .bat  con el siguiente texto:

```
"C:\Program Files\R\R-4.2.1\bin\Rscript.exe"  --vanilla --slave "C:\Users\comp\Desktop\prueba\script.R" quit
```

Si ejecuto el .bat se ejecuta el script y aparece el resultado creado.

Hasta ahí bien.

Ahora tengo un script hecho en rmarkdown llamado "fichero.Rmd" que crea un word.
Aparte tengo un fichero llamado "render.R"

El fichero render contiene

```
library(knitr)
library(rmarkdown)
setwd('C:/Users/comp/Desktop/prueba2')
rmarkdown::render("fichero.Rmd")
```

Si abro "render.R" y lo ejecuto, se crear el word.

Ahora el paso es no tener que abrir R. La idea es crear un .bat que ejecute render y q este sea el que llame a "fichero.Rmd" y que se cree el word.

Pero no funciona.
Pongo lo mismo que en el primer ejemplo y nada.

```
"C:\Program Files\R\R-4.2.1\bin\Rscript.exe"  --vanilla --slave "C:\Users\comp\Desktop\prueba2\render.R" quit
```

Actualizo:
si en el fichero render pongo

```
   library(rmarkdown)

    setwd('C:/Users/comp/Desktop/prueba2')

    write.table(iris, file = "Ejemplo1.txt")

    rmarkdown::render("fichero.Rmd")

    write.table(iris, file = "Ejemplo2.txt")
```

Y ejecuto el bat, me crea el ejemplo1, pero no el word ni el ejemplo2.

Comment: Algunas cosas para verificar rápidamente: 1) ¿Dónde se encuentra el Fichero.Rmd?, debería estar en C:/Users/comp/Desktop/prueba2 2) Quita la opción `--slave` para ver los mensajes de error

Comment: El fichero está en la ruta correcta. De hecho me guarda un fichero .txt, por lo que .bat conecta con "render" y este se ejecuta. No da mensajes de error. Me da que puede ser cosa del antivirus, pero no puedo quitarlo pq tiene contraseña del administrador. Las cosas del trabajo. Si lo ejecuto desde Rstudio no da problema. Tal vez Rstudio tiene permiso del antivirus y el bat no.

Comment: Eventualmente podría ser eso, prueba crear un archivo word (No Word) mediante  `write.table(iris, file = "fichero.docx")` a ver si el AV te lo bloquea. Prueba quitar el --Slave para ver si te da mensajes de error. Prueba tambien hacer lo mismo mediante R.exe: `R.exe -f "C:\Users\comp\Desktop\prueba2\render.R"`

Comment: fichero.docx me lo crea pero no puede abrirlo, "contenido no legible". Poner en el bat R.exe -f "C:\Users\comp\Desktop\prueba2\render.R" tal cual, no hace nada.

Comment: No, no te lo va a abrir por que lo que generamos no era un word, solo fue una prueba para ver si efectivamente el AV te está bloqueando esta generación y pareciera que no.

Comment: he probado con "C:\Program Files\R\R-4.2.1\bin\R.exe"  CMD BATCH "render.R" y he obtenido un fichero de error. No tengo pandoc. El caso es que si abro R y pongo rmarkdown::pandoc_available()  me sale TRUE rmarkdown::pandoc_version()  sale ‘2.18’.  pero si añado esas lineas a render.R y ejecuto el bat y luego miro la salida de error me sale FALSE y 0

Comment: Creo que esto puede explicar tu problema: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41269784/pandoc-while-using-r-markdown-with-a-cron-command

Comment: Tenía un perro llamado Bingo!!!!  Para saber donde esta pandoc rmarkdown::find_pandoc() Hay que poner la ruta en render.R de esta forma Sys.setenv(RSTUDIO_PANDOC="C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/quarto/bin/tools"). Gracias mil Patricio.